# JDBC thin adapter could not establish connection on peak times

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a java servlet application running on Tomcat8 over Windows Server 2012 r2.
Oracle 11g r2 is serving on different machine with same subnet, so no firewall exist between java application and oracle.

The java application is multi-threaded and has a haavy load on peak times.

my question is; when everything is alright and working fine below exception occurs.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor189.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.mulberry.request.MulberryRequestProcessor.run(MulberryRequestProcessor.java:168)
at com.mulberry.request.MulberryRequestProcessor.lambda$run$0(MulberryRequestProcessor.java:78)
at com.mulberry.request.MulberryRequestProcessor$$Lambda$32/461612128.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:277)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:181)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:633)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:186)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
at com.mulberry.data.connection.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:86)
at com.mulberry.data.MulberryOrm.getConnection(MulberryOrm.java:103)
at com.mulberry.data.MulberryOrm.insertMulti(MulberryOrm.java:201)
at com.mulberry.data.MulberryOrm.upsertMulti(MulberryOrm.java:192)
at com.aril.profile.service.impl.LprBulkdataService.saveLoadProfileData(LprBulkdataService.java:86)
... 11 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:161)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428)
... 30 more
```

When this exception occured on oracle site; 
dedicated user count : ~5200
(Also more than 1 tomcat instace is running with same purpose)

oracle parameter sessions is setted 12000
oracle running machine is also windows server 2012 with 64 cpu and 96GB ram

I am using tomcat jdbc connection pool and applications getting connections under tomcat pool.

Connection string is

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@[IPADDRESS]:1521/[SERVICENAME]
```

Ethernet between servers are 10gbit so dont think about network delay.

Can anyone help me to detect my problem ?

Comment: If it works except during periods of high load then the problem is most likely on the DB server side.  "Connection Refused" is very specific and it means the server actively rejected the connection attempt, maybe because it was overloaded or out of some resource.  You will need to pursue this by checking the server logs and talking with your DBA.

Answer (score 0):

you can set timeout ;

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", "dbuser");
props.setProperty("password", "dbpassword");
props.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, "2000");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("<JDBC connection string>", props);
```